# VSFTPD setup on Centos new virtual user cant connect

Tags: centos, ftp, database, vsftpd

I have a vsftpd server configured on centos. Old users that are listed in logins.txt can login via wb browser. Problem is that when I create a new user I can't login *530 bad login error*.

Steps taken to create user login: add user name and password to logins.txt, in user directory I create user config file:

```
anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO
anon_other_write_enable=NO
anon_upload_enable=NO
dirlist_enable=YES
download_enable=YES
local_root=/var/ftpdata/user
write_enable=YES
```

and create home directory in /var/ftpdata/user

after this I perform comand to load new user to database

```
db42_load -T -t hash -f logins.txt vsftpd.login.db
```

and restart service

```
/etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

So the main problem is that the older user can login but the newly created user can't login

Comment: i forgot to mention that i set virtual as owner of dir

Answer (score 0):

You adding you users in logins.txt. But server uses vsftpd.login.db for password check. I think, you need to re-hash your password file afte adding new user.

You can create a script for automatic adding users (convert.sh) :

```
#!/bin/bash

db4.8_load -T -t hash -f logins.txt logins.db
chmod 600 logins.db
```

create.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=$1
PASS=$2

echo "$USER"+"$PASS"

#adding user and updating db
echo "$USER" >> logins.txt
echo "$PASS" >> logins.txt
db4.8_load -T -t hash -f logins.txt logins.db
chmod 600 logins.db

#creating homedir
mkdir /home/ftp/$USER
chown virtual:virtual /home/ftp/$USER
chmod 555 /home/ftp/$USER

#creating config
cd /etc/vsftpd/users_config/
touch "$USER"
echo "local_root=/home/ftp/$USER" >> "$USER"
echo "write_enable=YES" >> "$USER"
echo "anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES" >> "$USER"
echo "anon_other_write_enable=YES" >> "$USER"
echo "anon_upload_enable=YES" >> "$USER"
echo "chroot_local_user=YES" >> "$USER"
```

Set permissions and mod:

```
$ chmod 700 convert.sh 
$ chmod 700 create.sh
```

Comment: how can i do that? as far as i know new pasword and user are loaded to db by this comand db42_load -T -t hash -f logins.txt vsftpd.login.db

Comment: yes, it is. I will add more info to my previous answer. Waite a minute, please

Comment: strange thing is that befor all i had to do is excecute comand db42_load -T -t hash -f logins.txt vsftpd.login.db and i could login but now something whent not as it suposed to

Comment: when i open my vsftpd.db i see that new user is added but i still cant login via browser

Comment: Have you configured PAM service for vsftpd?

Comment: '#%PAM-1.0
#session    optional     pam_keyinit.so    force revoke
#auth       required pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/vsftpd/ftpusers onerr=succeed
#auth       required pam_shells.so
#auth       include password-auth
#account    include password-auth
#session    required     pam_loginuid.so
#session    include password-auth
auth required /lib64/security/pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd_login crypt=hash
account required /lib64/security/pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd_login crypt=hash'

Comment: my pam.d for vsftpd looks like this

Comment: is the db has name vsftpd_login? sure, that not vsftpd.login? (see your post: db42_load -T -t hash -f logins.txt vsftpd.login.db). Try to rename vsftpd.login to vsftpd_login

Comment: You are welcome